# How to execute multiple SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 statements without executing SET ROLE every time in Go?

Tags: mysql, go, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html) in order to SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3. I'm using the instructions [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) for the Go implementation.

I want to execute two or more SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 statements. My code looks like this:

```
func main() {
    cfg := mysql.Config{
        User:                 "mydb_user",
        Passwd:               "mydb_pass",
        Net:                  "tcp",
        Addr:                 "database-1.cluster-falexpegpmn8.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306",
        DBName:               "mydb",
        AllowNativePasswords: true,
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())

    _, err = db.Exec("SET ROLE AWS_SELECT_S3_ACCESS")

    _, err = db.Query("SELECT * FROM items_20231026 INTO OUTFILE S3 "+
        "'s3://falex-aurora-backups/mysqldumps/2023/10/26/mydb-items_20231026-AAA' "+
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' MANIFEST ON")

    _, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM items_20231026 INTO OUTFILE S3 "+
        "'s3://falex-aurora-backups/mysqldumps/2023/10/26/mydb-items_20231026-BBB' "+
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' MANIFEST ON")
}
```

The first SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 succeeds. The second, however, fails with an error:

```
Error 1227: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SELECT INTO S3 privilege(s) for this operation
```

To avoid the error, I have to execute SET ROLE AWS_SELECT_S3_ACCESS again before the second SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 statement.

My question is how do I modify the code so that I don't have to keep executing SET ROLE AWS_SELECT_S3_ACCESS again and again whenever I need to execute a SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3 statement?

Comment: As stated in the docs you linked, `SET ROLE` applies to the active session (i.e. connection). The `DB` returned by [`sql.Open`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) "maintains its own pool of idle connections", meaning each of your `Query` calls may run over a different connection. In fact, as you don't close the `Rows` returned by `Query`, I believe its certain that different connections will be used. You can use [`Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Conn) to access a single connection (but use `db.Exec` when running the `SELECT INTO`).